# Bootstrap modal is not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap modal as a requirement of my project, the problem is that I'm unable to trigger this modal using jQuery

this is the modal code:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button> -->

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Please choose if you want to open an existing ticket or to create a new one.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">New Ticket</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Open Ticket</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the button from which the modal should be triggered:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="button" id="btnLogin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And finally this is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnLogin").click(function () {
            alert("..");
            $("#myModal").modal();
            alert("..");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that the script code is not executing after triggering `#myModal` element

Any suggestion please?

Comment: `modal('show')` ?

Comment: @Roberrrt thanks dear, even this is not working, I tried also `modal('toggle')` but also doesn't working

Comment: did you include bootstrap library in your project?

Comment: Sure !! @pumpkinzzz , already I'm using other bootstrap features and all are working fine

Comment: Is there any error in your console?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but unfortunately it didn't resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

use that you should put some parameter in .modal("hide") or .modal("show")

```
 $("#myModal").modal("show");
```

and please use this button

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="button" id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but unfortunately it didn't resolve my issue

Comment: you are over killing it . you have trigger your modal by your button data-target and the jquery script

Answer (score 1):

Here you go i already fix for you.

**reminder** always put jquery first after bootstrap.

**Example**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

i don't know why you need to add that script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnLogin").click(function () {
            alert("..");
            $("#myModal").modal();
            alert("..");
        });
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rh7h3bpq/1/)

Comment: dear, the demo u have provided is not working, the button is not triggering

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove your javascript! There's no need for that...

Bootstrap will already open dialog reading the attributes `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` on your button

So your javascript is causing the closure of modal right after it opens.

See this demo: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ufs7oux1/)

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, your demo is working perfectly, but when I'm trying to use it in my project it doesn't work!

Comment: Ok got it!, I get the code worked by having the jquery script source before bootstrap!

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnLogin").click(function () {

            $("#myModal").modal('toggle');

        });
    });
</script>
```